# Convert TimeStamp from database to Day laravel

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel

I want to convert a date I queried from the database, to explain it further here is my code on views.

```
    @foreach($myquery as $mydate)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ Date::createFromFormat('l',$mydate->logon)}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

what I want to output is just the Day, Example: mondays, fridays etc
$mydate->logon outputs 2014-11-25 10:28:09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to get the name of the day, after converting your time into Unix Timestamp .
For converting your time to Unix timestamp you can use

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

use the 'l' modifier, for the full textual representation when using the date function . so in laravel you can get desired output with

```
{{date('l',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}
```